# Is there a way to access how many unique agents a resource unit has interacted with?

Tags: anylogic

How can I access how many unique agents a specific unit of a resource pool has interacted with? For context, I would like to trigger an event when a certain resource unit has interacted with 17 unique agents.

Comment: How many agents? Or how many unique agents?

Comment: Question edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by creating a resource type.

[image]

Add a collection to that agent.
[image]

Then, in the on seize resource pool block, write the following code:

```
unit.seizedAgents.add(agent);
```

And then, in the on release field write:

```
if( unit.seizedAgents.stream().distinct().count() == 17 ) {
  <action >;
}
```

[image]

Of course, make sure to set the resource pool type to the right one.